# Bluetooth re-connect button never works until service restart - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I need to re-connect my paired Bluetooth headphones every evening to my PC. I turn on my headphones (not into pairing mode and ensuring they are not connected to anything), then I open Settings > Bluetooth on my PC and click the connect button. It never fails to **instantly** give the "That didn't work..." error message until I manually turn off the Bluetooth slider, wait 3 whole minutes, then turn it back on, and *then* pressing connect works just fine. However, I know it's not my headphones as pressing connect on my phone works just fine without needing to restart Bluetooth.

If there is no complete solution, is there at least some CLI/batch script I can throw together to automate toggling Bluetooth without all the delay and jank that comes with the terrible settings app?

Comment: Are there headphone batteries and are they new? Whenever either of my 2 Bluetooth mice do not pair quickly and properly it is because the mice batteries are low.

Comment: Brand-new headset. Plus I have it on charger overnight most nights to be extra sure.

Comment: Maybe update your Bluetooth driver.

Comment: Went through and tried to update all Bluetooth drivers to be sure. Already up to date according to Windows. It's using just the generic Intel driver, and my motherboard manual never states any specific driver being needed.